# Get data from postgreSQL from Liferay UI

Tags: postgresql, liferay

I installed PostgreSQL and Liferay. I created `portal-ext.properties` file in the root of my liferay directory. And now I want to check it. I have got a database `test` and table `tbl`. Is it possible to check how it works using only UI without using JAVA? 
Here is my configuration file that located in the root liferay folder **portal-ext.properties**

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
jdbc.default.username=postgres  
jdbc.default.password=root
```

Comment: Check how it works? I don't understand what you are asking for...

Comment: What are you trying to do?